# how to insert data from textbox to access database using where in c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Hi guys I have Access database that have some data on it  and the ID is Auto Number ex ID 17 , and a Column under name phone number ex: 222  , so I want to now enter another phone number to same column phone number cuz this person have two phone number

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText = "insert into data ( [Phone number] ) values ('" + textBox3.Text + "') WHERE [ID] like  '" + textBox15.Text + "'  ";
cmd.Connection = con;
con.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Data Inserted Successfully");
con.Close();
```

Comment: Insert is for adding a new row. If you want to add/change data to an existing row use `update`.. Also using `like` but not having any `%` is just like using `=`

Comment: INSERT inserts a NEW record and don't need any WHERE, if you want to UPDATE an EXISTING record then you use UPDATE with a WHERE condition

Comment: Also this approach is fundamentally flawed. You need a foreign key on this table that links the phone numbers to their owners

Comment: thanks guys I will use update but I want add this new phone number not remove it or change it to another  number, or if I used foreign key in  search will it bring all numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
 cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
 cmd.CommandText = "insert into [data] ( [Date],[Name] ) values ('" + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "')";
 cmd.Connection = con;
 con.Open();
 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
 System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Data Inserted Successfully");
 con.Close();
```